# HTMLSpanner. Incorporate into Eclipse project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, shared-libraries

I've been using `Html.fromHtml` to display html text into a `TextView` but am not completely happy primarily because it doesn't support **bullet points (li, ol)**.

I've run across `HTMLSpanner` (at https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner) and it looks like something worthwhile exploring.

Trouble is, I'm using `Eclipse` and, being somewhat new to this world of `java`, am not clear as to how to incorporate that code into my project.

I have incorporated other private libraries (like `sqliteassethelper` & `photozoom`), but `HTMLSpanner` is confusing me.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Right, after getting help from the author of HtmlSpanner (Alex Kuiper), here's what needs to be done:

1. Retrieve Jars. You need HtmlSpanner and HtmlCleaner. These can be acquired from the [Pagecleaner repo](http://repo.pageturner-reader.org/net/nightwhistler/htmlspanner/htmlspanner/0.5-SNAPSHOT/) (use the latest version) and [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner/htmlcleaner/2.2) (note: HtmlCleaner versions above 2.2 will NOT work)
2. Add them into your project as "External jars" (Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars). Also check them in "Order and Export"
3. Modify code. Replace `Html.fromHtml()` with `new HtmlSpanner().fromHtml()` as in `tv_question.setText(new HtmlSpanner().fromHtml(mtext));`

I needed HtmlSpanner primarily for the additional "list" functionality, so I've been focusing on that ... and found a few minor issues:

1. Nested lists. Need to add a break at the start of the child, as in `<ol><li>This is part of the parent list <br><ul><li>First child list item"`
2. Regular text following list. Need to add a paragraph break plus a regular break to get the single-line gap. As in `...list ended.</li></ul><p><br>Regular paragraph started...`
3. The numbered list. Does not provide a blank after the "number.". As in, `<ol><li>Apples` (and all subsequent list items) will show up as "1.Apples", not "1. Apples". I have not found a workaround for this.
4. Underline. `<u>...</u>` does not work.

My environment: Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse 4.2.1 (Juno), Android API 20

Overall, a fantastic set of classes that I am thrilled to have access to. Many thanks, again, to Alex.